# Add css class to Ember.Select

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to add css class to Ember.Select view:

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="kpiTypes" valueBinding="model.amount" optionValuePath="content.value" optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
```

adding just class don't work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `classNames` property:

```
{{view Ember.Select classNames="foo bar"}}
```

Comment: worked! (can't accept answer in 7 minutes :) )
where i could learn how to customize views? (adding some events etc.)

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html in the section RESPONDING TO BROWSER EVENTS

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I konw I'm really late. but this might save time for others who need help.

As Marcio said, you could use **classNames** if you want that as a static class to be added for your tag. 
If you need to bind a dynamic attribute as its class, we can make use of the **classNameBindings** keyword.

`{{view Ember.Select
                contentBinding="App.algosController"
                selectionBinding="App.selectedAlgoController.algo"
                optionLabelPath="content.algoName"
                optionValuePath="content.id"
                classNameBindings="App.selectedAlgoController.algo.algoType"}}`